# Angular dropdown not clearing items

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I have a form with two dropdowns (or select tags) one for countries and the other for states. The idea is that when you select a country that selection causes a call to be made that gets you a list of states/provinces for that given country. So it works for the most part however when the update to states list happens instead of clearing the list and adding the new items it just adds the new items to the existing list. Even though I set the component member back to an empty array. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would love some insight from my fellow developers.

Here is the HTML

```
 <!-- ROW -->
 <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group profile-group">
        <label for="country">Country:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Country" 
            (change)="countryChanged($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c.country_code">
             {{c.country_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group profile-group">
        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="State">
          <option *ngFor="let s of states" [ngValue]="s.state_code">
              {{s.state_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

And here is the component Type Script

```
 countries: Country[];
    states: State[];

    countryChanged(selected: string) {
    if (selected === undefined) {
      selected = this._customer.country;
    }

    if (selected.length > 2 ) {
      selected = selected.substr(selected.length - 2, 2);
    }

    this.states = [];
    this.getStates(selected).subscribe(data => {
      this.states = data as State[];
    })
  }

  getCounties() {
    return this.http.get(this.config.envSpecific.apiUrl + '/api/country');
  }

  getStates(countryCode: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.config.envSpecific.apiUrl + '/api/states/' + countryCode);
  }
```

Comment: You have your `[(ngModel)]="State"`, you don't have a `State` field, only a type

Comment: This code should work. Could you replicate the issue in demo (StackBlitz for example) with some dummy data?

Comment: I wasn't handling undefined states correctly. Not sure why that fixed it but it did

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this fixed it but when I put some code in to handle undefined states better it started working correctly